# Interface with Default Methods PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to create php classes which will handle all interaction with my database. At this point each class represents a table in my database and I'd like to create a Interface or Class to extend which contains the methods which are shared by all the Tables.

```
public static function find_by_sql($sql){
  global $database;
  $response = $database->query($sql);
  $object_array = array();
  while($next = $database->fetch_array($response)){
    $object_array[] = self::instantiate($next);
  }
  return !empty($object_array) ? $object_array : false;
}


private static function instantiate($result_array){
  $object = new static;
  foreach($result_array as $attribute=>$value){
    if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
      $object->$attribute = $value;
    }
  }
  return $object;
}
```

My problem is that the instantiate method needs to interact with attributes of it's child class. I'm used to working with java where I could define abstract getter and setter methods in an interface along with default methods to accomplish this. Is there something similar I can do in php?

Taking this a small step further I'd also like to be able to include the following method:

```
public static function find_by_id($id){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=\"{$id}\" LIMIT 1";
  $result_array = parent::find_by_sql($sql);
  return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}
```

where I get the table name from an implemented method or other function call which is available through php such as the get_class() function.

Comment: Use `abstract` classes. It's a normal class the cannot be itself `instantiated` with the `new` keyword. You can also use standard classes and extend from them. Depends on what you want to accomplish. `Interfaces` only is a kind of `meta` information that defines what need to exist but itself don't have any methods implemented.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that I can't call `find_by_sql()` statically from the class which is extending the abstract class so the use of `static` in `instantiate()` no longer works.

Comment: maybe [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some experimenting I've also found that an abstract class with late static bindings has the same effect as using a trait. Here's both ways of solving my problem:

Beginning with an abstract class:

```
abstract class Table{

  abstract protected static function get_table_name();

  public static function find_all(){
    $table_name = static::get_table_name();
    $result_array = static::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM {$table_name}");
    return !empty($result_array)? $result_array : false;
  }

  public static function find_by_id($id){
    $table_name = static::get_table_name();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE id=\"{$id}\" LIMIT 1";
    $result_array = static::find_by_sql($sql);
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
  }

  public static function find_by_number($number){
    $table_name = static::get_table_name();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE number=\"{$number}\" LIMIT 1";
    $result_array = static::find_by_sql($sql);
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
  }

  public static function find_by_sql($sql){
    global $database;
    $response = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while($next = $database->fetch_array($response)){
      $object_array[] = static::instantiate($next);
    }
    return !empty($object_array) ? $object_array : false;
  }

  private static function instantiate($attempt_array){
    $class_name = get_called_class();
    $object = new $class_name;
    foreach($attempt_array as $attribute=>$value){
      if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
        $object->$attribute = $value;
      }
    }
    return $object;
  }

  private function has_attribute($attribute) {
    $object_vars = get_object_vars($this);
    return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);
  }
}
```

Here the use of the `static` keyword to replace `self` as well as the `get_called_class()` method in `has_attribute()` allows for abstraction of the Table functionality.

Traits also allowed me to do everything that I was trying to accomplish. The user contribution notes in the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) describe them well:

> The best way to understand what traits are and how to use them is to look at them for what they essentially are:  language assisted copy and paste. If you can copy and paste the code from one class to another (and we've all done this, even though we try not to because its code duplication) then you have a candidate for a trait.

Here's the `trait` I created which could be used by my many classes:

```
trait Table {

  abstract static function get_table_name();

  public static function find_all(){
    $table_name = self::get_table_name();
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM {$table_name}");
    return !empty($result_array)? $result_array : false;
  }

  public static function find_by_id($id){
    $table_name = self::get_table_name();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE id=\"{$id}\" LIMIT 1";
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
  }

  public static function find_by_sql($sql){
    global $database;
    $response = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while($next = $database->fetch_array($response)){
      $object_array[] = self::instantiate($next);
    }
    return !empty($object_array) ? $object_array : false;
  }

  private static function instantiate($attempt_array){
    $object = new static;
    foreach($attempt_array as $attribute=>$value){
      if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
        $object->$attribute = $value;
      }
    }
    return $object;
  }

  private function has_attribute($attribute) {
      $object_vars = get_object_vars($this);
      return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);
    }
}
```